# Not able to get Azure AD token in C#

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory

I am trying to get azure ad token with following code

```
AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
string token = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceUri, clientID, 
                                             new Uri(redirectUri), 
                                             new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto))
                          .Result.AccessToken;
```

but after entering username password and otp for two factor authentication, I am getting the following error

> "error":"invalid_client",
> "error_description":"AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'.
> Trace ID: 1b452e84-a304-483e-adab-e19d1da28900
> Correlation ID: bbcfb9f5-999c-493d-bdea-5ef44c70ac1c
> Timestamp: 2023-01-04 03:25:22Z"
> "error_codes":[7000218],
> "timestamp":"2023-01-04 03:25:22Z",
> "trace_id":"1b452e84-a304-483e-adab-e19d1da28900",
> "correlation_id":"bbcfb9f5-999c-493d-bdea-5ef44c70ac1c",
> "error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=7000218"

Please resolve the issue

Comment: To resolve the error, create a client secret and pass it while generating the token.

Comment: to which method i need to pass client secret?

Comment: Did you enable `Allow public client flows` in the Azure portal?

Comment: I found a similar issue here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41730761/authenticationcontext-acquiretokenasync

Comment: after passing client id ,i am getting token without asking for username and password,i want password only after authentication

Comment: Can you confirm whether you are passing client secret or client id?

Comment: yes,now i change the code by passing both client secret and client id as bellow

            Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientCredential clientCredential = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientCredential(clientID, client_secret);
            var authenticationResult = await  authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceUri, clientCredential);

Comment: after above chenges i am getting token without poping up micrfofts username password asking box

authenticationResult contains the password

Comment: i need that pop up

Comment: Could you confirm which grant flow you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error as below:***

```json
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/token

client_id : xxxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx
grant_type : password
resource : resource
username : ruk@********.onmicrosoft.com
password : ******
```

[image]

> **Note** that : If the Azure AD Application is not a public client then **`client_secret`** is required. To avoid your Azure AD Application as public, you can create and pass the **`client_secret`**.

If you want to generate access token without `client_secret` then ***Enable  `Allow public client flows setting`  in your Azure AD Application***:

[image]

Generated access token without passing client_secret:

[image]

I agree with *wbosland*, **`AcquireTokenAsync`** is obsolete, and you need to make use of MSAL.NET to achieve your scenario by referring this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-migration-public-client?tabs=interactive):

```cs
var authResult = await pca.AcquireTokenInteractive(new[] { "User.Read" })
.WithAccount(accountToLogin) 
.WithParentActivityOrWindow(myWindowHandle) 
.ExecuteAsync();
}
```

As mentioned by you in the comments, you are making use of Client Credential flow which is meant for service-to-service communication without user interaction.

**References:**

[Acquire a token to call a web API interactively](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-desktop-acquire-token-interactive?tabs=dotnet)

[AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.authenticationcontext.acquiretokenasync?view=azure-dotnet)

Answer (score 1):

The [AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.authenticationcontext.acquiretokenasync?view=azure-dotnet) is obsolete. To migrate an app using Interactive flow, see https://aka.ms/adal-to-msal-net/interactive