# Is it possible to use MS Graph REST API to login a user in code and get an auth token?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm really after something like this: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-headless which used to work in version 3.9 but not now.

Specifically:
authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(todoListResourceId, clientId, uc).Result;

So is it possible to do the same thing using the REST API?

This is for a functional test so we can't allow the user to login normally. I need to replicate what a user would see after logging in.

Comment: Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41159005/1658906 ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible to acquire the token using the HTTP request directly for the **Resource Owner Password Credentials flow**.

We can use the Fiddler to capture the request to see the detail parameter required. And here is a code sample to use this flow to get the access token for the native client app:

```
string resrouce = "https://graph.windows.net";
string clientId = "";
string userName = "";
string password = "";

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();  
string body = String.Format("resource={0}&client_id={1}&grant_type=password&username={2}&password={3}", Uri.EscapeDataString(resrouce), clientId, Uri.EscapeDataString(userName), Uri.EscapeDataString(password));
StringContent sc = new StringContent(body,Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
var resoult= client.PostAsync("https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxx.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token", sc).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

And if you are working with web app, we need to append the `client_secret` parameter in the body.