# Programmatic testing of Azure AD B2C user workflows

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I have a set of services I am deploying to Azure that are currently guarded by Azure AD B2C. I would like to be able to write tests for some parts of this system (ie: regularly testing that our authorization workflows do their duty).

I was thinking of having these tests run through the login workflows automatically but from what I can see there's no easy way to acquire a token with a username/password programmatically.

I looked at the thread here: [headless authentication Azure AD b2c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35072371/headless-authentication-azure-ad-b2c/49036907#49036907) and the reply by @spottedmahn sort of helps, but it doesn't gain me a context from which I can, say, query the AD graph API for group membership.

Is there a API I can call to acquire a valid token from ADB2C?

(For what it is worth, our backend services are Ruby and Go, which do not have official ADAL libraries as of yet)

Comment: I guess you can call the REST API programmatically. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41149609/graph-api-authenticate-as-a-user-programmatically/41159005#41159005 this one is in c# though

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45341597/185123 ROPC flow...